# How to zoom in/out and move an element?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to display a Hex Grid, generated by [Honeycomb](https://github.com/flauwekeul/honeycomb) in an Angular component.
The grid can be a very big one, as the user chooses by himself the height and the width.

In order to handle that, I would like to have a zoom in and out system on the hex. Is the following code correct?

```
.zoom
  transition: transform .2s
  width: 200px
  height: 200px


.zoom:hover
  transform: scale(1.5)
```

Also, I'd like to allow the user to navigate through the grid, like in Google Maps. How to do that?

Comment: You can easily check that to know whether the code is correct or not... If it's work, it's more often correct than not

Comment: Agreed for the first question but what about the second one ?

Comment: That is another distinct question with no attempt at all. You should post it as a separate question and/or add your attempt to that

Comment: Yes, it would be better if you checked your solution first.. And then ask for help))

Comment: I would had better done check it first. Sory for the disagreement.